# Garbage Disposal only starts when manually kickstarted

Tags: garbage-disposal

Whenever I turn my garbage disposal on, it just makes the humming noise and doesn't spin. I tried using the wrench a couple times on the crank underneath and it moves freely but when I run to run it again it doesn't work. The only way it runs is if I turn it on and then use the wrench to kick start it while it is on. (That's not an ideal method because the wrench flies out once it starts!)  Then it runs normal until I turn it off and if I want to start it again I have to go through the same process. Is it a matter of a clog that I need clean out of it more (I've already tried Drano) or is the motor just burned out and I should replace it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like the motor is fine (once you have spun it up), but the motor starting switch/circuit has failed.

In today's market, replacement is probably the way to go.

Several decades back it might have been practical to take it to an electric motor shop and have the broken part only fixed, but in many places you won't even find such a shop any more.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense especially since it looks like I can get a decent one for under $100.